# Does the JSSOR slider have an option for image zoom after transition?

Tags: javascript, jssor

Does the JSSOR slider have an option for image zoom after transition?

I like the JSSOR slider better than all the others.  I am seeking one feature I have not yet seen though...

For example, see the "Ken Burns" style of the WOW Slider...

http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-bar-kenburns-demo.html

The zoom occurs after transition.  I see JSSOR has a zoom, but that feature seems to take effect during transition, not after.

Comment: For long run, I will look for a solution for kenburns effect. But there is no option to do this job at the moment.

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same thing. I'd like to use jssor instead of WowSlider, but I'd really like a Ken Burns pan-and-zoom transition. It has so many great transitions but is missing this classic.